# Script doesn't load on IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I got a problem with a script, when I try to load the page in IE7

[Link to the website](http://arojas.dinterweb.com/colono/donde.php)

> Expected identifier, string or number   zoommap.js, line 126 character 6

This is what is in that line:

```
    }).appendTo(map).click(function(){
```

> Object doesn't support this property or method   setupMap.js, line 6 character 1

This is what is in that line:

```
        $('#map').zoommap({
```

I hope that you can help me, I'll really appreciate it. If you need any other info please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that JavaScript does not support "final commas" in object definitions. So I cannot write:

```
var obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2,}
```

but have to write:

```
var obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: JavaScript does allow it (in the newest edition) and several browsers have allowed trailing commas for quite a while now.  Internet Explorer 9 also allows it.  IMO it promotes poor coding practices but it's not like I have to use it :-)

Answer (score 3):

The first means there is an extra trailing comma in the line above it.

The second is because the first failure causes the zoommap plugin to not initialize.